# Model conversion as fast as gurobipy and solved by open source solvers

Tags: solver, gurobi

Gurobipy is a fast solver and can convert a mathematical programming model to its underneath language very fast compared to some open source wrappers (e.g., PuLP, OR-tools, etc.). However, a commercial license is a big issue in some cases.

Is there any way to use a wrapper to convert models as fast as gurobipy, and solve with open source solvers? Alternatively, can we pass the model written with gurobipy to an open source solver?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `model.write("mymodel.lp")` to generate an LP file (similarly for `.mps` and other common formats) that you can pass in open source solvers, provided that they can read that respective format.

Since LP files are also human readable it is not too hard to transform a gurobipy model script into a script using only plain Python file operations that generates your LP file.

---

In order to make the second part of my answer a bit (in hindsight, it got out of hand) more succinct, I just give an example on how to generate an LP file "by hand" instead of using the gurobipy `Model.write()` method. For a minimal working example, consider the binpacking problem (how cliché).
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize } & \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} y_j\\
\text{subject to } & \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} w_i x_{ij} \leq Cy_j & j \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}\\
& \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_{ij} \geq 1 & i \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}\\
& x_{ij}, y_j \in \{0, 1\} & i, j \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using `gurobipy`, your file looks somewhat similar to this:

```
from gurobipy import *

# params
w = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3] 
C = 6
n = len(w)

model = Model('Binpacking')

x = {}
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(n):
    x[i,j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x#{}#{}".format(i, j))

y = {}
for j in range(n):
  y[j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y#{}".format(j))

model.setObjective(quicksum(y[j] for j in range(n)), GRB.MINIMIZE)

for j in range(n):
  model.addConstr(quicksum(w[i] * x[i,j] for i in range(n)) <= C * y[j], name="capacity#{}".format(j))

for i in range(n):
  model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j] for j in range(n)) >= 1, name="assignment#{}#{}".format(i, j))

model.write("binpacking.lp")
```

Using the same program structure (which is meant to be human readable, not necessarily optimal w.r.t. execution time), we can also create a similar file only using `write()`. It is a bit tedious but given the simple structure of LP files straight-forward:

```
# params
w = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3] 
C = 6
n = len(w)

model = open("binpacking.lp", 'w')

model.write("Minimize\n")
model.write("bins: ")
for j in range(n):
  model.write("+ y#{} ".format(j))

model.write("\n\nSubject to\n")
for j in range(n):
  model.write("capacity#{}:\n".format(j))
  for i in range(n):
    model.write(" + {} x#{}#{}".format(w[i], i, j))
  model.write(" - {} y#{} <= 0\n".format(C, j))

for i in range(n):
  model.write("assignment#{}:\n".format(i))
  for j in range(n):
    model.write(" + x#{}#{}".format(i, j))
  model.write(" >= 1\n")

model.write("\n\nBounds\n")
model.write("Binaries\n")
for j in range(n):
  for i in range(n):
    model.write(" x#{}#{}\n".format(i, j))
  model.write(" y#{}\n".format(j))

model.write("End\n")
model.close()
```

Comment: Note that, in some numerically unstable edge cases, going from internal binary representation to text file (LP, MPS, ...) and then back to binary at the other end can introduce problems, due to the rounding/truncation in moving from binary to text. I think most models will survive the process pretty well.

Comment: You cannot instantiate a model with gurobipy unless you have a valid license, so this answer is probably not applicable in the case when no license is available. (just tried it - you get an error if you execute `m = grb.Model("somemodel")`)

Comment: @prubin If you want to have a look at the model you can use LP - If you want to preserve precision, you should always use the MPS file format as it uses a higher precision compared to the LP file format.

Comment: @JakobS In the question is asked how to pass a model written by gurobipy to another solver. If this is already an issue one can build the LP file him/herself by just replacing `addConstr` and similar gurobipy commands by Python write operations which is also (very briefly) mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @JakobS: MPS is still an ASCII format, so there is still precision loss going to and from it. From the Wikipedia entry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_(format)): "Numeric fields have 12 characters width therefore limiting the precision."

Comment: @prubin: true, there might still be loss of precision, but it's better compared to LP which has even less precision afaik. It might be that at least for gurobi they save more digits as it is mentioned in the Wikipedia article under extensions (there it is called free MPS format). When I discussed something with the gurobi support team they always preferred MPS because of the better precision...

Answer (score 9):

If you do a lot of looping in Python to build your model, then model building is going to be slow. We have illustrated this for Pyomo (and the same undoubtedly holds for Pulp) in a notebook that implements the socalled [Wasserstein model](https://github.com/MOSEK/Tutorials/blob/master/wasserstein/wasserstein-bary.ipynb). Note this shows [Mosek Fusion](https://docs.mosek.com/9.0/pythonfusion/index.html) and [Cvxpy](https://cvxpy.org) is much faster than Pyomo for this particular model.

We tried to use the [fast expressions](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer_reference/expressions/performance.html) in Pyomo but it made no difference.

The key to the speed of MOSEK Fusion (and Cvxpy) is that it employs a vectorized notation which allows Fusion to move a lot of the model generation and input from Python to C based code.

Btw we are currently implementing the model using Julia JuMP. It is slower than both Mosek Fusion and [Cvxpy](https://cvxpy.org). We are quite surprised by that and do not know yet why.

Edit 2021-01-19: Here is the [Julia notebook](https://github.com/MOSEK/Tutorials/tree/master/wasserstein-julia) of Wasserstein problem.

Comment: Nice. Do you work around Python loops with similar tricks as Gurobi's `quicksum`?

Comment: See my expanded answer and the notebook referenced. I do not know the quicksum you reference.

Comment: Thanks. See [quicksum](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_quicksum.html). I think it avoids building up all of the intermediate results of adding one term to the partial sum so far.

Comment: I'm also curious about JuMP being slower than your Python example. I think the original benchmarks in the paper only covered MIP problems, but you probably have some cone problems to express?

Comment: I am not sure which paper you refer to. I refer to a Python notebook implemnting the Wasserstein problem.  If you take a look at that you can see the problem is a big sparse continuous LP. No conic or integer constraints.

Comment: I meant the [early JuMP paper](https://mlubin.github.io/pdf/jump-sirev.pdf) linked from my answer.
Your notebook doesn't yet contain the Julia code, right? So I assumed that it would be for another type of problem.

Comment: The Julia JuMP notebook will be published soon. It is the same problem as in the Python notebook.

Answer (score 6):

So I experimented somewhat with the formulation generation in pulp and profiled it. The biggest time sink hole was string creation.

This can be resolved by using f strings in Python 3.6+

This lead to a more than 2X speed up for formulating models.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a Python library in particular?
If you are happy using [Julia](https://julialang.org/), you should give [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl) a try.
It will give you high-level modeling with [fast model generation](https://mlubin.github.io/pdf/jump-sirev.pdf) and connection to most solvers.

In addition if you resolve basically the same problem just with some changed parameters [Parametron](https://github.com/tkoolen/Parametron.jl) allows you to do that fast enough to be usable in the inner planning loop of humanoid robots.

Comment: Jump can be slower than the best Python APIs. See my reply above. We will soon release a notebook showing that.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK Does this issue still exist? How does Parametron compare?

Comment: My guys tells my that https://github.com/MOSEK/Tutorials/blob/master/wasserstein-julia/wass-bary-julia.ipynb runs in about the same speed at Mosek Fusion for Python. So Python can be as fast as Julia for some models at least. I would think Julia is faster than Pyomo though. Parametron I do not know what is.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK https://github.com/tkoolen/Parametron.jl

Comment: Have not tried it. Mosek Fusion can do something similarly.